# How to keep an id accessible throw different routes without passing it in every route?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, eloquent, crud

I trying to implement a CRUD web-app that shows specific products to specific customers. I made the customer_id a foreign key to the products, and the relationship between customers and products one to many (one customer can have many products). Now I do not know the correct implementation to pass the customer_id through different routes. I am using Laravel, Eloquent, and Vue (I am new to all of these).

This route is in my customers page so when i try to access the products this route works

```
<router-link :to="`/products/${customer.id}`">Products</router-link>
```

When i get redirected to the products page i get the products correctly, but when i try to edit or add a product the code wont work. I tried passing the customer_id but i get undefined in this route.

```
<router-link :to="`/products/${product.id}/edit`" >Edit</router-link>
```

Is there a way to save the specific customer_id and keep using it?

Comment: is the customer_id the id of the user performing the request? if so you don't need to pass it at all since the server performing authentication will know to what user this token belongs to.

Comment: I have a user that gets a table with multiple customers and each customer can have multiple products based on the customer_id

Comment: so the customer is not a user?

Comment: yes the customer is not a user